# How to boot and install windows 7 back? Removing Ubuntu

Tags: windows

I need to revert back to Windows7 for some reasons, I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed. I have extracted my windows7 iso and copy it to a pen drive but when I restart my laptop I cannot boot it, F12 wont work.

I've been searching around but I don't understand how to fix this issue, what is the simplest way to go back to Windows7?

Comment: you dont have to copy, you have to burn the ISO. [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu) on how to burn windows iso on ubuntu

Comment: @edwardtorvalds My sleekbook does not have a cd drive, I can only boot through a USB drive.

Comment: using `winusb` you can burn ISO on USB also

Comment: How, exactly, did you 'extract the windows iso' - I'm not quite clear what sort of file we're looking at here - I doubt it's what you think it is!

Comment: @edwardtorvalds Installed that, didnt know it will wipe everything on my pen drive. lost all my work files :(

Comment: @MarkWilliams I right click and extracted the windows iso and copy the files onto the pen drive, I thought it will be the same thing.

Comment: Right-click.... what?

Answer (score 0):

How to burn installer to USB:

1. Copy Windows .iso to computer.
2. Launch `Startup Disk Creator`: press `ctrl+alt+T`, type `usb-creator-gtk`; or find it with gui.
3. Follow instructions of `Startup Disk Creator`, do not look at the title.

Comment: Wont load my windows ISO.

Comment: Then it is not Windows7 disk image

Comment: If you recall your key, you may download one from the net and simply use your key, else you have three options: 1) start loving Ubuntu <- preffered; 2) get another disk from somewhere; 3) resort to piracy

Comment: Btw, I setup one Ubuntu machine to look (and behave, lel) exactly like WindowsXP, should be possible like Windows7 too, the only problem would using programs written for Windows only.

Comment: I need to revert back to windows for gaming and work(photoshop). I had a original copy of windows7 but I lost the key, I am resorting to piracy.